# ER Diagram with multiple weak entities

Tags: entity-relationship

I had to design a database, and i didn't knew if it's right or not

**Scenario**
I have a entity Category. Then there are sub categories which are dependent on these categories. Each sub Category may or may not have some Products. Every Product may or may not have some information and then there is saving for each product. Now each products may or may not have savings data.

**My Solution**
[image]

Now i am unsure, if my ER Model is right or not

And if i were to convert it into Schema, Will my savings table have all the keys cascaded down from the Category table itself i.e

Savings = (CatId,Sub Cat Id, Product Id,Saving)

Product = (CatId,Sub Cat Id, Product Id, Description)

Sub Category = (CatId, Sub Cat Id, Sub cat Name, Description)